# Infix function evaluation with $

Tags: haskell

$ is an infix operator with the lowest possible precedence:

> f $ a = f a

Does this not mean that, in the expression below, the part

> $ 2 ^ 2

should be evaluated first and then add $ 2? It appears 2 + 2 is evaluated first

> Prelude> (2^) $ 2 + 2

returns :

> 16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Try to think of precedence not as being about what gets "evaluated first", and more about where parentheses are inserted.

The fact that `$` has the lowest precedence means that parentheses are inserted around everything to the right of it (and, separately, to the left of it, if needed, but they aren't needed here). So

> (2^) $ 2 + 2

is equivalent to

> (2^) $ (2 + 2)

which is of course

> (2^) 4          (i.e. 16)

Comment: so haskell evaluates right to left as when you add parenthesis all terms have same precedence?

Comment: It's actually a little more complicated than that: it will always try to evaluate the "outermost" function/operator first, then anything it needs to evaluate in order to do so. So it will try to evaluate the `$` first - because that's outside all parentheses - but to do so it needs to evaluate `(2^)` applied to `(2+2)`; in order to evaluate that it has to work out `2+2`, so in practice that's the first numerical operation that gets carried out, but it's not really because it's going right-to-left.

Answer (score 2):

Precedence rules can be confusing, but I like to think of it as "lower precedence" means "do later". Since `$` has the lowest precedence (for example, below `(+)`), it is performed *after* `(+)`. Thus `(2^) $ 2 + 2` evaluates `(2^)` to a partially applied function, then evaluates `2+2` to `4`, then applies `4` to `2^` to get `16`.

Comment: I tend to get confused about what "low" and "high" precedence mean; it helps me to think of `$` as binding very loosely, and `&&` binding more tightly than `||`.